# Undefined method `user_path' in test Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I run test rspec and display error:

```
Failure/Error: before { visit user_path(user) }
   NoMethodError:
     undefined method `user_path' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UserPages::ProfilePage:0xcd1f7c0>
```

How correct setting route for test?

**user_spec.rb**:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "profile page" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before { visit user_path(user) }

      it { should have_content(user.name) }
      it { should have_title(user.name) }
  end
  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_content("Sign up") }
    it { should have_title(full_title('Sign up')) }
  end
end
```

My **routes.rb**, where added i route get '/users/:id', to: 'users#show', :as => :user

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'static_pages#home'
  match '/help', to: 'static_pages#help', via: 'get'
  match '/about', to: 'static_pages#about', via: 'get'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact', via: 'get'
  match '/signup', to: 'users#new', via: 'get'

  match '/signin', to: 'sessions#new', via: 'get'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: 'delete'
  get '/users/:id', to: 'users#show', :as => :user

  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
```

Explain me, please, how correct add route for test rspec. I use rails 4. M

Comment: Change `describe "profile page" do` to `describe "profile page", type: :feature do`

Comment: Eureka! Works! But, tell me, why :feature?

Comment: You are using `rspec-rails` gem. It includes couple of modules, so-called example groups. How it works is that this gem configures rspec to automatically include those example groups when some metaparams are matched. `feature` example group extends basic behaviour with couple methods like `page` or `visit` and includes all url_helpers (which are not included in basic example groups).

Comment: In my case I had to include the `url_helpers` in my Rspec configuration, like `config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`, inside of `spec_helper.rb`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added type: :feature to describe "profile page" do and issue was fixed. Thank you,  [BroiSatse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2336231/broisatse)!